# Magento 1810 + 9767 v2 files

Tags: magento-1.8, supee-9767

Do anyone have Magento 1.8.1.0 9767v2 files.
I want to apply the patch manually.

Please send us if any has this patch files for Magento 1.8.1.0.

Comment: https://github.com/borriglione/SUPEE-9767/tree/master/plain_v2 download and open in text file

Comment: @RamaChandran think is more an answer than a  comment :)

Comment: Some time I Excited :)

Comment: thanks but when I do sh file I observed no files changed in the magento

Comment: this is why i am looking for zip file to upload manually